# tensorboard visualization site can not be reached

Tags: tensorflow, visualization, tensorboard

I am following this website's tutorial to learn tensorboard. But it does not show anything in http://172.17.0.2:6006 I have no idea why this happens. I try to debug with this command line: `tensorboard  --logdir=/notebooks/tmp/tensorflow_logs/example --debug`. Info as following

```
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is in debug mode.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting TensorBoard in directory /notebooks
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard path_to_run is: {'/notebooks/tmp/tensorflow_logs/example': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Event Multiplexer initializing.
INFO:tensorflow:Event Multiplexer done initializing
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is tag: 39
Starting TensorBoard 39 on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://172.17.0.2:6006)
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard reload process beginning
INFO:tensorflow:Starting AddRunsFromDirectory: /notebooks/tmp/tensorflow_logs/example
INFO:tensorflow:Adding events from directory /notebooks/tmp/tensorflow_logs/example
INFO:tensorflow:Constructing EventAccumulator for /notebooks/tmp/tensorflow_logs/example
INFO:tensorflow:Done with AddRunsFromDirectory: /notebooks/tmp/tensorflow_logs/example
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard reload process: Reload the whole Multiplexer
INFO:tensorflow:Beginning EventMultiplexer.Reload()
```

Any idea how to deal with this problem? Thx

Comment: "Does not show anything" -- as in there's nothing listening on that port, or a blank page, or some other error?

Comment: How do you handle your summary nodes? How do you use the `tf.summary.FileWriter`?